# android webrtc in wifi works on mobile chrome but not with android apk using TURN configuration

Tags: android, google-chrome, webrtc, turn, coturn

For one of the webrtc android application using Pion WebRTC as SFU, I am trying to apply TURN(coturn) server

In my setup Mobile is connected to home WiFi network -> Internet

When I test the client application as web app on Mobile Chrome(Chrome app installed on Mobile) connection succeeds and it works

But on same mobile if I build a native android apk, the webrtc connection does not succeed

I tried multiple variants of coturn configs like opening all UDP ports etc but still no luck

Its as below:

*Signaling Plane:*
Mobile -> [Internet(TCP WebSocket)] -> Pion WebRTC(On AWS EC2 in Docker)

*Media(RTP) Plane:*
Mobile -> [Internet] -> CoTURN(On AWS EC2 in Docker/Host(Both I tried)) -> [Internet] ->  Pion WebRTC(On AWS EC2 in Docker)

For Ref Anonymized:

> AWS TURN Server: 24.213.75.176
> Pion WebRTC Client/Peer: 10.0.2.7
> Mobile, External/IP assigned by ISP: 59.106.33.65

Below are the ICE candidates with Mobile Chrome[**This Works!**]

Pion WebRTC -> Mobile Chrome

```
"candidate:1581461838 1 udp 2130706431 10.0.2.7 47043 typ host","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:3149500351 1 udp 16777215 24.213.75.176 57960 typ relay raddr 10.0.2.7 rport 55304","mLineIndex":"0"
```

Mobile Chrome -> Pion WebRTC

```
"candidate:750856811 1 udp 2122262783 2406:b400:d4:9cf8:f408:748a:1958:f3e9 41224 typ host generation 0 ufrag WYhi network-id 5 network-cost 10","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:2131708102 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.0.100 48191 typ host generation 0 ufrag WYhi network-id 4 network-cost 10","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:124496459 1 udp 2122131711 2401:4900:2147:430f:345b:965b:514d:3a95 39210 typ host generation 0 ufrag WYhi network-id 1 network-cost 900","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:2169945122 1 udp 2122066175 2409:4030:4dc1:98ee:8a25:edc3:fa28:f41f 47075 typ host generation 0 ufrag WYhi network-id 3 network-cost 900","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:918013364 1 udp 2121998079 10.3.222.211 39867 typ host generation 0 ufrag WYhi network-id 2 network-cost 900","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:4266086002 1 udp 1685987071 59.106.33.65 14114 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.100 rport 48191 generation 0 ufrag WYhi network-id 4 network-cost 10","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:1648547483 1 tcp 1518283007 2406:b400:d4:9cf8:f408:748a:1958:f3e9 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag WYhi network-id 5 network-cost 10","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:831304758 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.0.100 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag WYhi network-id 4 network-cost 10","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:1239963323 1 tcp 1518151935 2401:4900:2147:430f:345b:965b:514d:3a95 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag WYhi network-id 1 network-cost 900","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:3486859474 1 tcp 1518086399 2409:4030:4dc1:98ee:8a25:edc3:fa28:f41f 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag WYhi network-id 3 network-cost 900","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:2016688452 1 tcp 1518018303 10.3.222.211 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag WYhi network-id 2 network-cost 900","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:835469592 1 udp 25042687 24.213.75.176 53424 typ relay raddr 59.106.33.65 rport 14115 generation 0 ufrag WYhi network-id 4 network-cost 10","mLineIndex":"0"
```

Below are the ICE candidates with Android APK on same Mobile[**This DOES NOT Work!**]

Pion WebRTC -> Android APK

```
"candidate:1581461838 1 udp 2130706431 10.0.2.7 49719 typ host","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:3149500351 1 udp 16777215 24.213.75.176 50026 typ relay raddr 10.0.2.7 rport 33690","mLineIndex":"0"
```

Android APK -> Pion WebRTC

```
"candidate:750856811 1 udp 2122262783 2406:b400:d4:9cf8:f408:748a:1958:f3e9 46293 typ host generation 0 ufrag oW1r network-id 7 network-cost 10","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:2131708102 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.0.100 49331 typ host generation 0 ufrag oW1r network-id 6 network-cost 10","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:124496459 1 udp 2122131711 2401:4900:2147:430f:345b:965b:514d:3a95 43435 typ host generation 0 ufrag oW1r network-id 3 network-cost 900","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:2169945122 1 udp 2122066175 2409:4030:4dc1:98ee:8a25:edc3:fa28:f41f 44867 typ host generation 0 ufrag oW1r network-id 5 network-cost 900","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:918013364 1 udp 2121998079 10.3.222.211 43305 typ host generation 0 ufrag oW1r network-id 4 network-cost 900","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:559267639 1 udp 2121940223 ::1 39589 typ host generation 0 ufrag oW1r network-id 2","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:1648547483 1 tcp 1518283007 2406:b400:d4:9cf8:f408:748a:1958:f3e9 43041 typ host tcptype passive generation 0 ufrag oW1r network-id 7 network-cost 10","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:831304758 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.0.100 47341 typ host tcptype passive generation 0 ufrag oW1r network-id 6 network-cost 10","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:1239963323 1 tcp 1518151935 2401:4900:2147:430f:345b:965b:514d:3a95 41293 typ host tcptype passive generation 0 ufrag oW1r network-id 3 network-cost 900","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:3486859474 1 tcp 1518086399 2409:4030:4dc1:98ee:8a25:edc3:fa28:f41f 40189 typ host tcptype passive generation 0 ufrag oW1r network-id 5 network-cost 900","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:2016688452 1 tcp 1518018303 10.3.222.211 48263 typ host tcptype passive generation 0 ufrag oW1r network-id 4 network-cost 900","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:1876313031 1 tcp 1517960447 ::1 41935 typ host tcptype passive generation 0 ufrag oW1r network-id 2","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:4266086002 1 udp 1685987071 59.106.33.65 14977 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.100 rport 49331 generation 0 ufrag oW1r network-id 6 network-cost 10","mLineIndex":"0"
"candidate:835469592 1 udp 25042687 24.213.75.176 51541 typ relay raddr 59.106.33.65 rport 14978 generation 0 ufrag oW1r network-id 6 network-cost 10","mLineIndex":"0"
```

I tried with multiple version of Google android-webrtc like:
*org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.27771* and *org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006* But same behavior

Android APK code I configured as:

```
PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302").createIceServer(),
PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("turn:TURN_SERVER:3478?transport=tcp")
                    .setUsername("username1")
                    .setPassword("password1")
           .setTlsCertPolicy(PeerConnection.TlsCertPolicy.TLS_CERT_POLICY_INSECURE_NO_CHECK)
                    .createIceServer()
```

I tried to change TLS_CERT_POLICY_INSECURE_NO_CHECK with and without here too same behavior

RTCConfiguration as below:

```
rtcConfiguration.iceTransportsType = PeerConnection.IceTransportsType.ALL;
rtcConfiguration.bundlePolicy = PeerConnection.BundlePolicy.MAXBUNDLE;
rtcConfiguration.sdpSemantics = PeerConnection.SdpSemantics.UNIFIED_PLAN;
```

I doubt exactly how on same mobile with Mobile Chrome App WebRTC works and **not with Android APK build** with **TURN** configuration?

Same APK works if both peers say *Android APK and Pion WebRTC peers* are in same network, basically with *host network*

Any suggestions / guidance will really help

Thanks

Comment: May I ask what is the selected candidate pair in your mobile chrome ? Does it use relay or srflx ? 
If it used relay, you could check the coturn log to see whether the android sdk get the relay address successfully or not

Comment: hi did you manage to solve?